# Donde debo tener mis paquetes en eclipse

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse, maven

[image: Eclipse]

Donde debo agregar mis paquetes de "controller", "domain", "security", "infra", vengo de usar Intellij pero tengo que hacer este projecto en eclipse pero no se como organizar los paquetes, veo que en el projecto por defecto tiene una carpeta llamada src y unas subcarpetas main y test, debo crear los paquetes hay o debo crear yo mis paquetes en la carpeta fuente src/main/alura

Comment: lee acerca de esa convención acá: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este proyecto tiene la clásica estructura que usa Maven, en `src/main/java` añades tus clases principales y el `src/test/java` las clases de tus tests.

Por tanto, si quieres crear una clase que esté en el paquete com.alura.controller, el directorio debería ser `src/main/java/com/alura/controller`

Comment: Cuando te refieres a directorio es "paquete" ?